# IE11 calculates the height of parent flex container incorrectly

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to use a flexbox-based layout to display a page with a sticky footer. This works well with short pages (less than the height of the window) in all browsers. However, the same approach with long pages works in Firefox, but IE11 cuts the container element to about 25% of the child element.

Here is the example: https://codepen.io/vers/pen/rraKYP

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
div.container {
  max-width: 600px;
  background-color: #aaa;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
div.content {
  margin: 8px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
div.header,
div.footer {
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>...</p>
      <!-- 40 long paragraphs here -->
    </div>
    <div class="footer">Footer</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use the `height` property, some browsers will interpret that as the limit. As an alternative, use `min-height`.

Instead of this:

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Just use this:

```
body {
  min-height: 100vh;      
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

[revised codepen](https://codepen.io/vers/pen/rraKYP)

Alternatively, this also works:

```
html {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

[revised codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wzBbgA)

Both methods tested in Chrome, FF, IE11 & Edge.

Answer (score 0):

IE11 has problems in flexbox with vh units. You can change the `body` height to 100%.

Comment: Works for me in IE11 on windows 7

Comment: Curious, now doesn't work. but works deleting the height in `body`